# iOS Development: iPhone-only app behaves different on iPad compared to simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios8, ios-simulator

I'm developing an iPhone-only app. When I simulate it on iPad 3rd gen. (iOS 8.0), it acts like as universal app, I mean the app is full screen and there is no x2, x1 choices on the corner. 
On the other hand, when I simulate it on simulator (iPad Retina, iOS 8.1) on mac, it behaves like iPhone-only app that is what I expect.

- I check targeted device, build settings and it is iPhone.
- I copy source files to new project and nothing's changed. ( not settings, only source files).
- I disable size classes change them to iPhone and still nothing's changed.

What do you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: do you have launchScreen xib or storyboard?

Comment: I don't have any launch screen. I use mainstoryboard as launch screen file.